# I need to run jenkins job on Monday and Thursday so will the following expression do it for me?

Tags: jenkins, cron, cronexpression

I need to schedule the Jenkins job on live environment every Monday and Thursday of the week.

Will the below expression help me out? Secondly I want to run it not at a single time ie want to distribute the load. So I've read about the Hash feature implemented in Jenkins. Can anyone tell me how to use that with the current expression or the new expression incase below expression is wrong?

```
00 19 * * 1,3,5
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is incorrect --  it will schedule a build every Monday (1), Wednesday (3) and Friday (5) at 7pm (19:00).

This will do what you want:

```
H H * * 1,4
```

The hash identifier "H" maps to a fixed number within the permitted range; the number is derived from the name of the job. So,

- for the *same* job, "H" will always correspond to the same numbers (here: hours and minutes), but
- *different* jobs will run at a different time

which will thus evenly distribute your builds over a 24 hour period.

Comment: So how do I run my Job on a given time? ie If I want the job to be running post lunch maybe by 2 PM so what changes do I need to make in the above expression that you mentioned?

Comment: For 2pm use `0 14` instead of `H H`. Note that the hash feature can only be used to distribute the start time of _different_ jobs. It is not meant to specify distributed execution of _one and the same job_ over a certain period.